# liftIO instead of composition lift

Tags: haskell

> Down in this document, we call liftIO in eval6 to perform I/O actions.
>   Why do we need to lift in this case? Because there is no IO class for
>   which we can instantiate a type as. Therefore, for I/O actions, we
>   have to call lift to send the commands inwards. For eval6 , we would
>   need to compose lift four times to print something. This is just
>   inconvenient, so people create a new class MonadIO such that we only
>   need to call liftIO once, without having to keep count of how many
>   times to compose lift:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadIO m where
liftIO :: IO a -> m a
instance MonadIO IO where
liftIO = id
instance (Error e, MonadIO m) => MonadIO (ErrorT e m) where
liftIO = lift . liftIO
instance (MonadIO m) => MonadIO (ReaderT r m) where
liftIO = lift . liftIO
```

The citation comes from http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/personal/Transformers.pdf

And again, I cannot understand why withoud liftIO we would have to call liftIO four times. I cannot see it therefore please make clear it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MonadTrans t where
  lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
```

If you want

```
foo :: Monad m => m a -> ExceptT e (StateT s (ReaderT r m)) a
```

then you need to apply `lift` once for each of the type constructors. First we get

```
lift :: Monad m
     => m a -> ReaderT r m a
```

then

```
lift . lift :: Monad m
   => m a -> StateT s (ReaderT r m) a
```

then

```
foo = lift . lift . lift :: Monad m
   => m a -> ExceptT e (StateT s (ReaderT r m)) a
```